# Combining data and task parallelism for machine learning in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, machine-learning, distributed-computing, cross-validation

Apache Spark provides data-parallel implementations of machine learning algorithms. It has also started to support task parallelization of machine learning algorithms, e.g., in the context of cross-validated parameter tuning, for example using Spark's Scikit-learn integration package: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-spark.html

My question is, what would be the recommended approach(es) for combining these two modes of parallelism in Spark:

1. Execute the ML algorithm on distributed data, and
2. Execute multiple instance of the algorithm (using different tuning parameters) in the same framework?

Keep in mind that, task parallelism in this context still involves a 'gather' stage where results (e.g., cross-validated errors) from each task must be combined (e.g. minimized); so tasks are not completely independent.

Comment: This is primary opinion based question thus off-topic.

Comment: I am actually curious where is a programming question here. Is there any particular issue you're trying to solve. If you're asking about concept yourself than https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ are much better place to ask.

Comment: @zero323: I am not sure if this post is really appropriate for data science or stats forums. The question is really about software system architecture, rather than machine learning or statistical algorithms per se. Can you suggest a more appropriate venue, given the focus of my question?

Comment: Truth be told I am not exactly sure :) If it is more architecture problem  then  https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ could a better place to seek help. Still... Have you tried anything? Do you have any particular architecture in mind? If you try to make your question more specific then it will be easier to either help or redirect you.

Comment: Thank you @zero323, the programmers forum seems more appropriate. As for your question: While I haven't tried anything specific yet, but I do have a general constraint: I want to use Spark as much as possible. For example, for data parallelism, I want to continue to use Spark. So the architectural degrees of freedom are mainly with regards to the choice of task-parallelization strategy. If this was pure task parallelism, I would have gone with any standard cluster manager software, but since there is a gather phase, and potentially more complex control flow, I need something more ML-aware.

Comment: Without strict specification it is really hard to give you any programming specific advice. Personally I still believe that it is more statistical model specific question. Depending on your assumptions about data distributed approximation vs. assemble of local (close to) exact one approach can be better than another. It is really hard to find a scenario when both are good. There is also a matter of latency which will be fundamental for streaming jobs but less important for batch.